# Configure nginx language subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm moving a site from apache to nginx and stuck with the following configuration.

I have site http://example.com/ which shows the main (English) version.
Also, I have a few more languages which could be opened using correspondent subdirectories.
http://example.com/de http://example.com/fr, http://example.com/es or http://example.com/es/ (with a trailing slash).

These subdirectories are virtual (non-existing), but should open the same pages from the root directory. A php script handles the language representation.

Now English site works fine, however, other languages don't work.
I can open http://example.com/es/ (only with a trailing char) and it opens the main page, however, all other pages could not be accessed (e.g. http://example.com/es/test.html which is a seo friend url). I already reviewed lots of similar questions and answers on SO but non of them are helpful.
Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    ....
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
  
    location / {
            rewrite ^/(de|fr|it|es)\/(.*)$ /$2;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
            rewrite  ^(.*)$ /seo.php?$args last;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpeg|ico|jpg|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|gz|wof|csv|zip|xml|yml) {
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri @static;
            expires 14d;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            root /var/www;
    }

    location @static {
            rewrite ^/(\w+)/(.*)$ /$2 break;
            access_log off;
            rewrite_log off;
            expires 14d;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            root /var/www;
    }

    location /backend/ {
            
            rewrite  ^(.*)$ /backend/index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

It previously worked on apache as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(de|fr|it|es)\/(.*)$ $2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend|template)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpeg|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ seo.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously Apache is transforming `/es` to `/es/` before applying the rewrite. `nginx` will not do that unless the directory actually exists.

However, it is easily remedied by tweaking the regular expression, and making the trailing slash optional.

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/(?:de|fr|it|es)(?:/(.*))?$ /$1;
```

The `(:?   )` construct is a non capturing group.

EDIT:

If you want the trailing slash to be added "visibly", then you will need a redirect. For example:

```
rewrite ^/(de|fr|it|es)$ /$1/ permanent;
rewrite ^/(?:de|fr|it|es)/(.*)$ /$1 last;
```

Comment: Now if I try to open example.com/de it opens an English version instead and not adding a trailing slash (what I'm trying to reach). And any other urls inside language subdirectories still not working. e.g. example.com/de/test.html (seo friendly url).

Comment: I have added the redirect option to append the trailing slash. Regarding your second problem, what is the error and does `/seo.php` get executed?

Comment: Thank you for you help. Directory works now. URL re-writing is also working. The problem appeared to be the following: If I try to access a php script which should not be re-writen e.g. example.com/de/api.php it seems it routes to seo.php as well and then 404 error is showing. if I try to access example.com/api.php (without language directory) it works.

Comment: Have you tried moving the rewrite directives outside of the location block. That might cure the `example.com/de/api.php` problem which is caused by the `location ~ \.php$` block intercepting the URI before `location /` gets it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Richard Smith :)

I am using an Angular 13 app with an Nginx server for a Blog and the expected URL is -

```
**English content (Default)**
    www.site.com/blog/en
    www.site.com/blog/en/the-world-is-waiting-for-you-2022
**Hindi language content**    
    www.site.com/blog/hi
    www.site.com/blog/hi/the-world-is-waiting-for-you-2022
```

**My Nginx Configuration:**

```
# if request is /blog
location ~* /blog {
    # http to https redirection
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http' ) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    # execute default file
    index index.html;
    # root folder where angular code 'blog' folder exists
    root /site/stage.example.in;
    # if url has language code /blog/en, /blog/hi, ... 
    # then rewrite request to index.html
    rewrite ^/(?:en|hi)(?:/(.*))?$ /$1;
    # check file, folder/, point /blog/index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ @blogfallback;
    # my error and access log
    access_log /site/stage.example.in/logs/access.log;
    error_log /site/stage.example.in/logs/error.log;
}
# from /blog/en or /blog/hi last rule execution
location @blogfallback {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/index.html?$args last;
}
```

**Inside blog folder-**

```
blog
 ├── assets
 │   ├── fonts
 │   │   ├── montserrat-medium-webfont.ttf
 │   │   └── roboto-v18-latin-regular.woff2
 │   ├── images
 │   │   ├── master.jpg
 │   │   ├── home
 │   │   │   └── icons
 │   │   │       └── sample.png
 │   │   ├── icons
 │   │   │   ├── static_icons
 │   │   ├── search_hover_icon.png
 │   │   ├── static
 │   │   │   ├── blog
 │   │   │   │   ├── save-icon.png
 │   │   │   │   ├── banner_1366x290.jpg
 │   │   │   │   └── share-icon.png
 │   └── json
 │       ├── listing.json
 │       ├── common.json
 │       └── details.json
 ├── favicon.ico
 ├── index.html
 ├── main.33y3y.js
 ├── polyfills.sgsg53t.js
 ├── runtime.353gghegh.js
 ├── scripts.36sgsg.js
 └── styles.ss4647.css
```

The angular app needs to execute each request via index.html.

***since the url structure is /blog/en -- nginx expecting a folder 'en' inside 'blog'.***

but, these are virtual folder, which does not exists on the server.

***hence we need to guide nginx that -***

if users enter the url /blog -- go to root folder 'blog' and run index.html.

if user enters the url /blog/some-file.css or some-file.js -- go and check
if file exists in "blog" folder,
if yes, open it
else check if any folder exists with the same name in "blog" folder.

if yes, open it.

***if all fails point that request to /blog/index.html.***

now, there is no folder and files exists for the example request, /blog/en/a-beautiful-world

-- nginx points that request to /blog/index.html as fallback and angular routes that request and execute with a proper modules, controller, etc.

--
Thanks